# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 after adding a new class into a project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

After i included a [custom badge](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge) files into my project, project is failing to build with the following error. Note, that there are not syntax errors anywhere, such as missing includes etc.

[image]

**What may be going on here please? Clean succeeded. Build failed.**

[Header file for the class i included](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge/blob/master/Classes/CustomBadge.h) contains:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Note that needed frameworks are included:

[image]

Also, i tried removing/ adding frameworks from the project, that did not seem to do anything to help with this issue.

---

### **[ANSWERED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763602/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-after-adding-a-new-class-into-a-project/9763689#9763689):**

Make sure to include the files you just added into the project by going to `Targets -> Build Phases`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add both the `CustomBadge.h` **and** `CustomBadge.m` files into your project when you build it, otherwise all you have is a declaration of a class without the corresponding definition, this is what leads to an error like this. It is, in essence telling you that you have told it to expect the implementation by `#import`ing the `.h` file, but if you don't bring along the `.m` file then it will be unable to make use of it.

Comment: The reason why you don't need to add the QuartzCore framework is because the CoreGraphics framework references it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877987/whats-the-difference-between-quartz-core-core-graphics-and-quartz-2d