# How can I animate a box to expand and contract on touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, easing

I read the intro to core animation from Apple, searched all over for 'ios tweening,' 'ios easing,' and related thins but surprisingly came up empty handed.

How can I make my UILabel contract and hide its subview buttons while keeping the UILabel showing? Links, code, design overview, or anything that gets this done will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Can you just have a view behind the label that expande its frame height when the label is touched?

Comment: Wain, that is nicely crafty and I will probably do that until I find an optimal solution. But I won't get to use the nifty animation effects shown at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161465/how-to-create-custom-easing-function-with-core-animation

Comment: Sure you could use those, it's just a different way of animating the view frame...

Comment: You need to animate the changes in frame.  Here is an answer I wrote in the past that is applicable to your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765577/how-can-i-make-this-animation-effect-in-iphone-development-quartz2d-core-anima/16765737#16765737

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprised no one stepped to this, the answer is pretty straightforward. But maybe that's why.

I'm not sure about animating the UILabel itself, though as it is a subclass of UIView, I suspect it would be fairly normal.

The simplest way to get this done is to use the UIView static method:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                 animations:(void (^)(void))animations
```

In my case, I have a UILabel, `myLabel` on top of a UIView `myContainer` with a UIButton `dismissButton`. Presuming I want `dismissButton`, when clicked, to roll up `myContainer` I would Crtl-drag my `dismissButton` button to the proper `viewController.m` and in the `-(IBAction)` method write:

```
-(IBAction)dismissButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                    animations:^{ 
           [self.myContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,frame.bounds.size.width,20)];
           [self.dismissButton removeFromSuperView]; }];
}
```

Note: This is from my limited memory, so point out any errors.

Note2: If you are using this to help yourself, **watch those semicolons, brackets and braces**

Now, most people reading this for reference might want more functionality that clicking a button which rolls up a view forever. There are more detailed animateWith* methods.

There is

```
+(void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

which allows a completion block to be done once the view is finished animating. **Note from Paul Hegarty's iOS class:** You may call more animate methods from your completion block.

There is another animation method that lets us specify animation options.

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

The options include:

```
enum {
   UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews            = 1 <<  0,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction      = 1 <<  1,
   UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState     = 1 <<  2,
   UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat                    = 1 <<  3,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse               = 1 <<  4,
   UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration = 1 <<  5,
   UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedCurve    = 1 <<  6,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent      = 1 <<  7,
   UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews   = 1 <<  8,

   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut            = 0 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn               = 1 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut              = 2 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear               = 3 << 16,

   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone            = 0 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft    = 1 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight   = 2 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp          = 3 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown        = 4 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve   = 5 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop     = 6 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom  = 7 << 20,
};
typedef NSUInteger UIViewAnimationOptions;
```

Hopefully someone can benefit from this long winded intro to animating a UIView.